# Elasticsearch index size is 40% larger in 5.x than in 1.x

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an old cluster running Elasticsearch `1.4.4`. 
My cluster is containing ~11 billion documents and the size of all primaries is around `4TB`.

I am now in the process of upgrading to Elasticsearch `5.2.2`, which of course means reindexing my data. I have a separate cluster where this is happening at the moment. I am reindexing from my source database, since I have `_all` and `_source` disabled on the original index.

I have now reindexed around 750 million documents and noticed that my new index size is already `350GB`. I did some math and it looks like the index will grow to around `5.5TB` when fully indexed. That's **1.5TB more** than the `1.4.4` index. I wasn't expecting this. On the contrary I was expecting a decrease in size, since I've removed several attributes. Is this a normal thing or did I do something wrong? Is there a different default settings in `5.2.2` that can contribute to this growth?

**1.4.4 index settings:**

```
{
  "index": {
    "refresh_interval": "30s",
    "number_of_shards": "20",
    "creation_date": "1426251049131",
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "default": {
          "filter": [
            "icu_folding",
            "icu_normalizer"
          ],
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer"
        }
      }
    },
    "uuid": "WdgnCLyITgmpb4DROegV3Q",
    "version": {
      "created": "1040499"
    },
    "number_of_replicas": "1"
  }
}
```

**1.4.4 index mapping:**

```
{
  "article": {
    "_source": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "_all": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "properties": {
      "date": {
        "format": "dateOptionalTime",
        "type": "date",
        "doc_values": true
      },
      "has_enclosures": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "feed_subscribers": {
        "type": "integer",
        "doc_values": true
      },
      "feed_language": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "author": {
        "norms": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "analyzer": "keyword",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "has_pictures": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "title": {
        "norms": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "type": "string"
      },
      "content": {
        "norms": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "type": "string"
      },
      "has_video": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "url": {
        "index": "not_analyzed",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "feed_canonical": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "feed_id": {
        "type": "integer",
        "doc_values": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**5.2.2 index settings:**

```
{
  "articles": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "refresh_interval": "-1",
        "number_of_shards": "40",
        "provided_name": "articles",
        "creation_date": "1489604158595",
        "analysis": {
          "analyzer": {
            "default": {
              "filter": [
                "icu_folding",
                "icu_normalizer"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "icu_tokenizer"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "0",
        "uuid": "LOeOcZb_TMCX6E_86uMyXQ",
        "version": {
          "created": "5020299"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**5.2.2 index mapping:**

```
{
  "articles": {
    "mappings": {
      "article": {
        "_all": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "_source": {
          "enabled": false
        },
        "properties": {
          "author": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false,
            "analyzer": "keyword"
          },
          "content": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false
          },
          "date": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "feed_canonical": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "feed_id": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "feed_subscribers": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false
          },
          "url": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help will be much appreciated since full reindexing on this cluster takes about 30 days... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be doc_values.
Since elastic 2.0, doc_values are enabled by default, meaning your 5.2 mapping creates doc_values for more fields than your 1.4 mapping, and that consumes disk space.

Comment: That was my initial thought as it looks like it's a common case. But if you see my 1.4.4 index, I have explicitly enabled doc_values there on the same fields that I've kept in the new index. There's only one boolean field that didn't have doc_values in the previous index, but I highly doubt that this overhead comes from it. If it does, then I'll be restarting the reindexing process, but I'm already 3 days in... how to be sure?

Comment: I count 2 fields that were not doc valued in 1.4, and are in 5:
url, feed_canonical. It could explain the size growth, even with the removal of 4 boolean attributes (which are probably highly compressible as they are and would not require much space).

Other than that, it would be useful to know how many nodes in the cluster, how many indices, shard size, are there any document routings in place, etc'.

Comment: If it's possible for you, maybe start a second ingestion process - in parallel with the first - with a modified 5 mapping, for a "good enough" amount of documents (100 - 200 mil), and then estimate the new size again

Comment: I didn't consider that the URL is a `not_analyzed` field. It could really be the culprit. I have started a parallel indexing and will report in a day or two when it the new index has grown enough. I didn't mention the specifications of the my cluster in order to keep this focused on index size, not performance. You can check my reply to @asettouf if you are curious.

Comment: You are correct to focus the question on the index size, but I didn't ask for machine specs, but other relevant configuration parameters, such as number of indices, number of shards (are they identical to the 1.4 cluster), routing of documents, and so on. These parameters can affect the compression rate of the data...

Comment: The number of shards has increased from 20 to 40. I don't use `_routing`. It is one huge index.

Comment: Increasing the number of shards also contributes to index size growth, but  It's hard to tell by how much.

Comment: 1 billion documents indexed with the new mapping, but I've made some extra changes. `doc_values` is off for the `url` field now. I have also removed the `author` filed as it's not used. Number of shards is now 10, because I decided to break down the huge index into "smaller" yearly indices. The index is still larger, but the increase is now only ~10%. So now `doc_values` are off where they were off before, there are 5 removed fields and number of shards is halved. Instead of getting smaller, the index is bigger. Still puzzling.

Comment: what about ids? are they the same ids as in the old cluster? Also, if i understand you correctly, you didnt bring the number of shards downs, but actually increased it to ~100 shards if counting all the yearly indices?

Comment: ids are the same (integers, inserting strictly in ascending order). I'm still filling up only the first index and my calculations are based entirely on it, so I'm counting only 10 shards. I might go with 6 shard setup in the future.

Comment: You count 1 billion documents with 10 shards, but the overall setup will be 11 billion with many more shards, so I think the final estimation is probably off. If you would have ingested to two shards (which is proportional for your 20 in the old cluster), i think the estimation would be more accurate, and the difference less than 10%. 

However, i'm not entirely sure that's all there is to it....

Answer (score 0):

I see you have modified the refreshing interval and put the number of replicas at 0,  if using spinning disk, you can add to the elasticsearch.yml to increase the indexing speed:

```
index.merge.scheduler.max_thread_count: 1
```

If you don't care about searching yet, the following on your ES5 cluster could also help:

```
PUT /_cluster/settings
{
    "transient" : {
        "indices.store.throttle.type" : "none" 
    }
}
```

Be sure you have swapping disable. How much memory is allocated to your nodes in the ES5 cluster? (You should use half of the total available memory of a node, with a cap at 32 GB due to memory addressing limit of Elasticsearch).

Also this increase in size might be because Elasticsearch does not merge its segments often, and will wait a calmer period to merge them and thus, reducing the size on the disk. As long as the reindexation is not over, it's a little bit early to judge on the overall size of the new index.

A few articles below that could help:

- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.x/tune-for-indexing-speed.html
- https://www.elastic.co/blog/a-heap-of-trouble

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Indexing speed is not my concern. It is doing pretty well. Servers are quite powerful and optimized for ES. What you say about segment merging is plausible and I've indeed noticed some fluctuation, but the index is still a lot bigger. I doubt it will shrink so much at the end only with segment merging.

Comment: I see though 30 days is a heck lot of days for the size you have (though I do not know the size of your cluster as well) About the disk space, this article shares an interesting experience by the way: https://blog.discordapp.com/how-discord-indexes-billions-of-messages-e3d5e9be866f#.6zzwqchb6

Comment: The cluster is happily running on 3 servers (adding 4th now), each with 64G RAM, 4x900GB SSDs. Source data is in 11TB worth of MySQL databases and they are production DBs running a busy service, so obviously I can't push them to their limits. The bottleneck is not ES. My only concern is the overall index size at the end.

Comment: Have to agree with asettouf on that one. 30 days is a long period of time for indexing 11 billion documents, small as they are. Unless you're absolutely confident in your ingestion process, I would seek ways to increase the read speed from your source database.